# $|a| \leq 1 \Longleftrightarrow[\forall z \in \mathbb{C}\;(|z|<1 \Longrightarrow\operatorname{Re}(1-a z)>0)]$

Tags: complex-numbers

I'm trying to prove the following equivalence ($a$ a complex number):$$|a| \leq 1 \Longleftrightarrow[\forall z \in \mathbb{C}\;(|z|<1 \Longrightarrow\operatorname{Re}(1-a z)>0)]$$

I calculated the real part of $1-az$ : $$Re(1-az)=1-\alpha x+\beta y$$ if we set $a=\alpha+i\beta$ and $z=x+i y$. But I can't get any further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $|a|\leqslant1$ and if $|z|<1$, then $|az|<1$, and therefore $\bigl|(1-az)-1\bigr|<1$. But then\begin{align}\operatorname{Re}(1-az)&=1+\operatorname{Re}\bigl((1-az)-1\bigr)\\&\geqslant1-\bigl|(1-az)-1\bigr|\\&>0.\end{align}And if $|a|>1$, take $z=\frac1a$. Then $|z|<1$ and $\operatorname{Re}(1-az)=\operatorname{Re}(0)=0$.

Comment: i tried to accept your answer, by they wont allow me hhhh , your response wase too fast, thank youuuu

Comment: Simpler (IMO): $\operatorname{Re}(1-az) = 1-\operatorname{Re}(az) \ge 1-|az| > 0$. It is of course equivalent to what you wrote.

Comment: @MartinR Indeed. But what I wrote was the first thing that popped into my head.

Comment: ... and I was still looking for a duplicate (which I did not find) when your answer appeared :) I was also not sure about the quality of the question and if it should be answered or not.

Comment: @MartinR I must say that I am not totally sure about that myself.